# Object from Class of Properties in vb

Tags: vb.net, properties, propertygrid

I have a property grid and I want to be able to set the selectedobject to a class. The class contains properties. This is what I have, but it 'OtherFiles' is not an object.

```
pgProperties.SelectedObject(OtherFiles)
```

How do you create a class as an object. In VB.NET 2008 please. C# is ok. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [`new`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fa0ab757.aspx) operator is used to create objects.

```
OtherFiles of = new OtherFiles();
```

The code above assumes an `OtherFiles` class exists and has a default constructor.